# Hanami repository delete/update operations using joins

Tags: ruby, sequel, hanami

I'm having some trouble doing delete/update operations using joins on a repository.
I have `Libraries` that belong to `Users` and have many `Books`, like so:

```
class LibraryRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    belongs_to: user
    has_many :books
  end

class BookRepository < Hanami::Repository
  associations do
    belongs_to :library
  end
```

Now what I want to delete a book entry, but only if it belongs to the user library. I was trying to do that using the following query:

```
books.join(libraries).where(libraries[:user_id] => user_id).where(id: id).delete
```

But I get the following error:

```
Sequel::Error: Need multiple FROM tables if updating/deleting a dataset with JOINs
```

Any suggestions into how I could do such a query?

Comment: Which version of Hanami do you use?

Comment: @AleksanderPohl version 1.2 of `hanami` and `hanami-model`

Answer (score 0):

I think Hanami do not support multiple from, but postgresql does

```
books.dataset.from(:books, :libraries).where(Sequel[:libraries][:user_id] => user_id, Sequel[:id] => id).delete
```

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.